# Is there a risk of installing Microsoft Edge on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016, microsoft-edge

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/about-microsoft-edge

> The Long-Term Servicing Branch (LTSB) versions of Windows, including Windows Server 2016, don’t include Microsoft Edge or many other Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. Systems running the LTSB operating systems do not support these apps because their services get frequently updated with new functionality. For customers who require the LTSB for specialized devices, we recommend using Internet Explorer 11.

So I was trying to install edge, and kept getting errors such as "You'll need an app to open Microsoft Edge", and on the edge download page the download link did nothing.

However, I was able to download the insider edition beta version of Edge, and from that navigated to the full version download and it allowed me. I then uninstalled the beta version and now seem to be utilizing the full version without issue on what apparently is not a supported operating system.

Is this "hack" or "workaround" going to come back to haunt me?

Comment: Why do you need Edge on a server?

Comment: @joeqwerty an associate of mine is a dedicated fan, but it's certainly not required. Just curious about the impact of the workaround.

Comment: @user1447679 Generalizing what joeqwerty was asking to make the question more clear, why would you need any web browser on a server?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist it's a web server, and we often test instances and apps in a local host environment which require a browser.

Comment: I would simply install firefox on such a server, but without setting it as the default browser (ie: leaving IE11 as the default one).

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way to download and install Edge.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download

- Select channel/version
- Select build
- Select platform
- Click download

Install the MSI file on the target systems.